# PHP header function behaves unexpectedly

Tags: php, header

I am testing below code where `<html>` tag is sent before I call header function. Ideally I should get 'Headers already sent' error. But to my surprise the page is redirected to google.com. Any idea why this happens?

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You probably have output buffering on

Comment: @John Conde.. I rechecked php.ini settings. Output buffer settings is commented out. That means by default it is turned off

Comment: As @JohnConde commented already, you have output bufferring on. It can aso be reproduced by calling `ob_start()` manually at some point of your script

Comment: Question: would it still redirect even after getting that error? (note that I'm not the op)

Comment: @user2354254 did you restart after making changes to the system file(s)? that's if you did make a change before? those won't take effect until you did restart, should it be the case.

Comment: @FirstOne Comments are not here to ask questions. If you want to do so, I suggest you to go to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and then [ask your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: @FirstOne Probably no, the second header would be ignored

Comment: also, is error reporting set to ON in system files? If not, add error reporting to the beginning of your file to see if it does trigger a headers sent notice.

Comment: @tektiv, well, my request for clarification is related to the question. Let me explain... If the code is going to run even **with** the error, we wouldn't have the oportunity to see it. That way, our premisse to the question would be false, invalidating the question!!!

Comment: @Fred -ii- I did turn on error reporting with error_reporting(E_ALL). It didn't work either

Comment: and did you restart all services if you made any changes? Plus, how are you accessing this file, as `file:///file.php` or `http://localhost/file.php`? Two different animals here @user2354254

Comment: @FirstOne Nah I was just kidding, since nowadays we have a lot of answer-comments and comment-answers :) Your comment is absolutely fine

Comment: well, no response. I guess you're busy trying to figure something out. Ping me if you want, I've left the question.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I am using `http://localhost/file.php`  I have restarted the services again now just to confirm. Still no luck